# Calculation of Food Score in Jawbone App

Tags: jawbone

how is the "Food Score" number - shown in the Jawbone App - be calculated;

thank you very much in advance for your help;

Best Regards

Rudolf

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this support article](https://jawbone.com/support/articles/000008889/foodscore), which goes into detail on the Food Score.

Here's a brief summary from the article:

> Food Score rates foods on a simple scale of 1 to 10, with 1 indicating
>   least healthy and 10 indicating most healthy. UP calculates the score
>   of individual items and full meals that you log in the app and
>   provides a rolling average for the day.